# How do I run an extensionless (maybe ELF) file on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was given a "binary" file on linux and a seperate file for windows for a particular task. The programs is an exe on windows. A linux version of the file has the same function on linux as it had windows, too.

However, I've failed to be able to execute this. I tried (on the terminal) to execute it by just the file name, `./[filename]`, and even tried `chmod +x [filename]` and then tried the second way.

For everything... I get the result: "Command not found". (The file is definitely there, by the way).

What am I supposed to do? The file command on it yields:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e805f746e65c09cc8b0c037d8a8c27ee0a6a051c
```

Comment: Are you by any chance running the same executable you used for Windows on Linux?

Comment: No, sir... I'm most certainly not!

Comment: using the file command yields this:
 ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e805f746e65c09cc8b0c037d8a8c27ee0a6a051c, stripped

Comment: Do you have a `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on your system? This will happen if you try to run a 32 bit executable on a 64bit system or vice versa without the required libraries installed, out if you run an executable compiled for a different distribution

Comment: I've got this: /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: You probably need to install 32 bits support files on your system. (i.e. `ia32*` or `lib32*` packages). Or even a chroot-ed thing with `debootstrap`

Comment: As `file` tells you, you very specifically need `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`. **It appears that you are trying to run an i386 executable on an amd64 system.** On Ubuntu/Debian systems, you could `apt-get install libc6-i386` to install the support libraries to run i386 executables.

Comment: Also, use `ldd` rather than `file` to show more informative details about the libraries required by the executable (possibly more than just libc6).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is that this is 32 bit compile on a 64 bit system. I cross compiled a small c file into a binary using the `-m32` option on gcc. This also needed a few extra packages. The resulting `a.out` looks like this.

```
% file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=be02470c8337b96e7deaaff323bc53865991c3ab, not stripped
```

Compare this to a native system binary

```
% file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a0823e17cafbe5b2296346216445566840fdfd88, stripped
```

Running the `a.out` shows me this.

```
% ./a.out
zsh: no such file or directory: ./a.out
```

The specific "Command not found" message is something, I think, bash prints. I use zsh myself.

To get this to work, you can install the multilib packages. I didn't narrow it down to the exact package but installing `gcc-multilib` on Debian pulls in everything you need. After installing that, here's what I get.

```
% ./a.out
3.140523
```

(the program is supposed to estimate the value of PI).

Note:  I actually needed to install `gcc-multilib` just to compile the file. I then uninstalled the packages to mimic a 64 bit system that doesn't have the 32 bit runtime libraries that the thing needs.

Comment: `apt install gcc-multilib`

Answer (score 0):

does the a.out have executable permission ?

check with ls -la cmd and if does no then add the permission using chmod a+x a.out an d then try executing

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33393091)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).